# Maior valor em um array no PHP

Tags: php, matemática, value

Estou com um problema em achar o maior valor da largura da caixa dos produtos para o frete de um site que estou fazendo.

Coloquei os dados dos produtos com o tamanho das caixas no banco de dados e estou agora fazendo os cálculos. Precisei somar o peso e as alturas como o cliente pediu e agora preciso pegar o maior comprimento e largura de um conjunto de produtos, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso...

Se alguém puder ajudar seria ótimo, segue o código abaixo:

```
$total = 0;
            $alturaTotal = 0;
            $pesoTotal = 0;
            $larguraTotal = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $quantidade)
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$id'";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
                {
                    $produto = $row['nome'];
                    $preco = $row['preco'];
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $altura = $row['altura'];
                    $largura = $row['largura'];
                    $comprimento = $row['comprimento'];
                    $peso = $row['peso'];
                    $cepOrigem = $row['cepOrigem'];

                    $sub = $preco * $quantidade;
                    $total = $total + $sub;

                    $alturaTotal = $alturaTotal + $altura;
                    $pesoTotal = $pesoTotal + $peso;

                    foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $largura)
                    {
                        $larguraTotal = $largura;   
                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lógica é bem simples, basta usar duas variáveis e verificar se o valor da largura/comprimento é maior do que o que está na variável, se for armazena a novo valor largura/comprimento nela. Exemplo:

```
// Declara as variáveis fora do loop
$maiorlargura = 0;
$maiorcomprim = 0;

// Atualiza o valor da variável dentro do loop
if ($maiorlargura < $largura = $row['largura'])
   $maiorlargura = $largura = $row['largura'];

if ($maiorcomprim < $comprimento = $row['comprimento'])
   $maiorcomprim = $row['comprimento'];
```

Quando o *loop* terminar, estará o maior valor na variável. Podes ainda pegar o ID do produto, atualizando uma variável para isso junto com largura/comprimento.

Comment: Cara brigadão ajudou bastante \o/